# Question about the latent variable in EM algorithm

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, latent-variable, finite-mixture-model

In mixture models, Expectation maximization algorithm (EM) is a commonly used method to estimate the model parameters. Suppose that I have bivariate mixture model with two mixture components, with mixture weights, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, respectively. EM introduces a $z$ variable which takes 1 if the point is come from the first mixture component, and takes 0 otherwise. These variables are assumed to be i.i.d and are distributed from multinomial ($\pi_1$, $\pi_2$). Is that correct? If yes, how they can have only {0,1} values and in the sometimes they have multinomial distribution?

Here is the paragraph from the source: [here is the link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256413527_Mixture_of_D-vine_copulas_for_modeling_dependence)

3.2. EM algorithm

In this section, we describe the EM algorithm (Dempster et al., 1977) to obtain the estimates for the parameters θ in a
mixture of M-component D-vine densities, given the data set and the number of components M. The determination of M
will be discussed later in Section 3.3.
Assume that N observations, say $x_k = (x_{k,1}, . . . , x_{k,N} )$ where $k = 1, . . . , d$, drawn randomly from a $M$-component.

Let us denote latent variables $z_{n} = (z_{n1}, . . . , z_{nm}, . . . , z_{nM})$, where $z_{nm} = 1$ if $x_{n}$ comes from the $m$-th component and
$z_{nm}$ = 0 otherwise. Assume that $z_{n}$ is independent and identically distributed from a multinomial distribution, that is,
$z_{n} ∼ Mult(M, π = (π_{1}, . . . , π_{M}))$.

Any help, please?

Comment: @Xi'an thank you so much for your answer, I add the link.

Comment: @Xi'an Ok. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion in the question, confusion that could be reduced by looking at a textbook on the paper, or even [the original 1977 paper](http://web.mit.edu/6.435/www/Dempster77.pdf) by Dempster, Laird and Rubin.

Here is an excerpt of our book, [Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa), followed by my answer:

> Assume that we observe $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, jointly distributed from $g({\mathbf x}|\theta)$ that satisfies
>   $$
> g({\mathbf x}|\theta)=\int_{\cal Z} f({\mathbf x}, {\mathbf z}|\theta)\, \text{d}{\mathbf z},
> $$
>   and that we want to compute $\hat{\theta} = \arg\max L(\theta|{\mathbf x})= \arg\max g({\mathbf x}|\theta)$.
>   Since the augmented data is ${\mathbf z}$, where $({\mathbf X}, {\mathbf Z}) \sim f({\mathbf x},{\mathbf z}| \theta)$
>   the conditional distribution of the missing data ${\mathbf Z}$ given the observed data ${\mathbf x}$ is
>   $$
> k({\mathbf z}| \theta, {\mathbf x}) = f({\mathbf x}, {\mathbf z}|\theta)\big/g({\mathbf x}|\theta)\,.
> $$
>   Taking the logarithm of this expression
>   leads to the following relationship between the complete-data likelihood $L^c(\theta|{\mathbf x},
> {\mathbf z})$ and the observed-data likelihood $L(\theta|{\mathbf x})$. For any value $\theta_0$,
>   $$
> \log L(\theta|{\mathbf x})= \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\log L^c(\theta|{\mathbf x},{\mathbf Z})] 
>     -\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\log k({\mathbf Z}| \theta, {\mathbf x})],\qquad(1)
> $$where the expectation is with respect to $k({\mathbf z}| \theta_0, {\mathbf x})$. In the EM algorithm,
>   while we aim at maximizing $\log L(\theta|{\mathbf x})$, only the first term on the right side of
>   (1) will be considered.
>
> Denoting$$
> Q(\theta |\theta_0, {\mathbf x}) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}
> [\log L^c(\theta|{\mathbf x},{\mathbf Z})],
> $$
>   the EM algorithm indeed proceeds iteratively by maximizing
>   $Q(\theta |\theta_0, {\mathbf x})$ at each iteration and, if $\hat{\theta}_{(1)}$
>   is the value of $\theta$ maximizing $Q(\theta |\theta_0, {\mathbf x})$,
>   by replacing $\theta_0$ by the updated value $\hat{\theta}_{(1)}$. In this manner, a sequence of estimators
>   $\{\hat{\theta}_{(j)}\}_j$ is obtained, where $\hat{\theta}_{(j)}$ is defined as the value of
>   $\theta$ maximizing $Q(\theta |\hat{\theta}_{(j-1)}, {\mathbf x})$; that is,$$
> Q(\hat{\theta}_{(j)} |\hat{\theta}_{(j-1)}, {\mathbf x})
> = \max_{\theta}\,Q(\theta |\hat{\theta}_{(j-1)},
> {\mathbf x}).$$This iterative scheme thus contains both an expectation step
>   and a maximization step, giving the algorithm its name.
>
> **EM Algorithm**
>   Pick a starting value $\hat{\theta}_{(0)}$
>
> Repeat
>
> 1. Compute the E-step
>      $$
>    Q(\theta|\hat{\theta}_{(m)}, {\mathbf x})
>    =\mathbb{E}_{\hat{\theta}_{(m)}} [\log L^c(\theta|{\mathbf x}, {\mathbf Z})]\,,
>    $$
>      where the expectation is with respect to $k({\mathbf z}|\hat{\theta}_{(m)},{\mathbf x})$ and set $m=0$.
> 2. Maximize $Q(\theta|\hat{\theta}_{(m)}, {\mathbf x})$ in
>      $\theta$ and take the M-step
>      $$
>    \hat\theta_{(m+1)}=\arg\max_\theta \; Q(\theta|\hat{\theta}_{(m)}, {\mathbf x})
>    $$
>      and set $m=m+1$
>
> until a fixed point is reached; i.e., $\hat\theta_{(m+1)}=\hat{\theta}_{(m)}$.
>
> For the normal mixture, using the missing data structure exhibited in previously leads to an objective function
>   equal to
>   $$
> Q(\theta^\prime|\theta,\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{2}\,\sum_{i=1}^n
> \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[\left. Z_i (x_i-\mu_1)^2 + (1-Z_i) (x_i-\mu_2)^2 \right| \mathbf{x} \right].
> $$
>   Solving the M-step then provides the closed-form expressions
>   $$
> \mu_1^\prime = \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i x_i  |\mathbf{x} \right] 
> \bigg/ \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i| \mathbf{x} \right]
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \mu_1^\prime = \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i) x_i  |\mathbf{x} \right] 
> \bigg/ \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n (1-Z_i)| \mathbf{x} \right].
> $$
>   Since
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}_\theta\left[Z_i|\mathbf{x} \right]=\frac{\varphi(x_i-\mu_1)}{ \varphi(x_i-\mu_1)+3\varphi(x_i-\mu_2)}\,,
> $$
>   the EM algorithm can easily be implemented in this setting.

Whatever the mixture involved, the latent variables $Z_i$ are Multinomial $\mathcal{M}_M(1;\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_M)$ which means only one component of the vector $Z_i$ is equal to one and all of the $M-1$ others are zero. (Note the difference with the question in the notations: the original notation $\mathcal{M}(M;\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_M)$ fails to indicate how many draws are taken, that is, what is the sum of the components of $Z_i$.).When $k=2$ as in the above excerpt, $Z_i$ is an integer in $\{0,1\}$. There may be a confusion between a [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) and the property of a distribution (like some mixtures) to be [multimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution). The $Z_i$ do not have a multimodal distribution, taking only two values, even conditional on the $X_i$'s, while the $X_i$'s may, at least unconditionally.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly read between the lines, your question is about the difference between the distribution of $[z]$ (i.e., the *prior* distribution of the latent variable), and the distribution of $[z \mid y]$ (i.e., the *posterior* distribution of the latent variable given the data $y$).

The prior probabilities are the same for all subjects, i.e., $\pi$. However, the posterior probabilities will be different per subject because each subject will his/her own probability of belonging in the first component (i.e., the component for which $z_i = 1$) depending on their data $y_i$. Hence, if you do the plot of the posterior probabilities, it can be multimodal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have updated my question to make it so clear.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo in my question. Could you please have a look. I meant multinomial, not multimodal.

Comment: Since the distribution has only $\{0,1\}$ as support, even a posteriori, I fail to see how it can be multimodal. Either $\mathbb{P}(Z_i=1|X_i)>.5$ or $\mathbb{P}(Z_i=1|X_i)><5$.

Comment: You’re right, I meant the posterior probabilities. I’ll edit my answer to make this clear.