# Latent variable in Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: unsupervised-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Whenever I look up material pertaining to Gaussian Mixture Models, it always mentions latent variable $z$, where $z \in \{1, ..., K\}$ and is one-hot encoded. I completely understand the objective of GMMs and how it is a linear superposition of Gaussians in the form $p(\textbf{x}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \pi_k\mathcal{N}(\textbf{x}\vert\mu_k,\Sigma_k)$, but I don't understand what purpose the latent variable serves in this and why a joint distribution needs to be defined in terms of the marginal $p(\textbf{z})$ and $p(\textbf{x}\vert\textbf{z})$. Is there an intuitive reason for the variable $\textbf{z}$?

Answer (score 3):

The latent variable $\mathbf{z}$ is the allocation vector that attributes to each observation $x_i$ of the sample its component indicator $z_i$, i.e.,$$\mathbb{P}(Z_i=\xi)=p_\xi\qquad\qquad X_i|Z_i=\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_\xi,\Sigma_\xi)$$The latent variable is used in the [EM algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371080/question-about-the-latent-variable-in-em-algorithm) and the [Gibbs sampler](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR). It is also a key notion behind [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) & [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification).